# Typescript template literals with inference

Tags: typescript, template-literals

A code convention marks the child of an entity (= an association with another entity) with a '$'.

```
class Pet {
  owner$: any;
}
```

When referring to an entity child, the user should be allowed to use the full form ('owner$') or a simpler form ('owner').

I'm trying such construct:

```
type ChildAttributeString = `${string}\$`;
type ShortChildAttribute<E> = ((keyof E) extends `${infer Att}\$` ? Att : never);
type ChildAttribute<E> = (keyof E & ChildAttributeString) | ShortChildAttribute<E>;

const att1: ChildAttribute<Pet> = 'owner$'; // Valid type matching
const att2: ChildAttribute<Pet> = 'owner'; // Valid type matching
const att3: ChildAttribute<Pet> = 'previousOwner$'; // Invalid: previousOwner$ is not an attribute of Pet - Good, this is expected
```

This works as long as ALL attributes of Pet are child attributes, but as soon as we add a non-child attribute, the matching breaks:

```
class Pet {
  name: string;
  owner$: any;
}
const att1: ChildAttribute<Pet> = 'owner$'; // Valid type matching
const att2: ChildAttribute<Pet> = 'owner'; // INVALID: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
// To be clear: ChildAttribute<Pet> should be able to have these values: 'owner', 'owner$'
// but not 'name' which is not a child (no child indication trailing '$')
```

What would be the proper types to make that work ?

**--- edit**

I haven't been clear on the expected result and the definition of an "entity child", hence the posted answers, so I edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we map over the keys: if a key ends with `$`, we include both full and short forms, otherwise we omit it:

```
type ValuesOf<T> = T[keyof T]
type ChildAttribute<E> = 
  ValuesOf<{ [K in keyof E]: K extends `${infer Att}$` ? K | Att : never }>

interface Pet {
    name: string
    owner$: any
}

type PetAttr = ChildAttribute<Pet> // "owner$" | "owner"
```

Comment: Simple and concise!
For me to have the expected result (I edited the question for clarification), the ending 'K' in ChildAttribute definition should be 'never', so 'name' will not be a possible value of it. Could be please edit it?

Answer (score 1):

`ChildAttribute` should return a union of all allowed values.

```js
type RemoveDollar<
  T extends string,
  Result extends string = ''
  > =
  (T extends `${infer Head}${infer Rest}`
    ? (Rest extends ''
      ? (Head extends '$' ? Result : `${Result}${Head}`) : RemoveDollar<Rest, `${Result}${Head}`>) : never
  )

// owner
type Test = RemoveDollar<'owner$'>
```

As far as I understand, if value is with `$` we can apply short getter but if property is without `$` like `name` - we can't use `name$` as a getter.

If my assumption is correct this solution should work for you:

```js
interface Pet {
  name: string;
  owner$: any;
}


type RemoveDollar<
  T extends string,
  Result extends string = ''
  > =
  (T extends `${infer Head}${infer Rest}`
    ? (Rest extends ''
      ? (Head extends '$' ? Result : `${Result}${Head}`) : RemoveDollar<Rest, `${Result}${Head}`>) : never
  )
// owner
type Test = RemoveDollar<'owner$'>

type WithDollar<T extends string> = T extends `${string}\$` ? T : never

// owner$
type Test2 = WithDollar<keyof Pet>

type ChildAttribute<E> = keyof E extends string ? RemoveDollar<keyof E> | WithDollar<keyof E> : never

const att1: ChildAttribute<Pet> = 'owner$'; // Valid type matching
const att2: ChildAttribute<Pet> = 'owner'; // Valid type matching
const att3: ChildAttribute<Pet> = 'previousOwner$'; // Invalid: previousOwner$ is not an attribute of Pet - Good, this is expected
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoTMg3gKGckOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG49kB7AdxGgBJy4QBPRgF8cIsHwAOKAEoQizAG4QAIswA2quFAA8TACrIIAD0ggAJhUrU6AGiYyKAV1WYjJ85ZohayALzIA5P5MAHy%20TAAU%20q4QZhYABpxYoDDQyAASEHCmgonJqfZggnFM%20AD8yOEFBsYx7oEl%20Mjl4RlZ1W4W-pz%20Tcj2TpjkCVj9zjlYrdlxAJTI5DJyiirqmloF1sjDo4WJk0XBs%20QcilBM0zgA9Bcs7NA4YpLIuhBUvn2yCspqGtr%20bBxQbrBUQSFAAdWAYAAFssfloojVYh46KE-AiOptElRPLRBAAdThxXr6I4QE4iK43AGce6gp4vMAAJjeEOhsNWAGsIHxmDA0BhgbTHgBhKHAVSmACCYCsACMHJAtABRVHILk8vlK9q1CzYui9BafdnadW85Aq5AAH2QrJh3053LNFtJ5JwCGYIFecBlAEZyKLxVKZTR5Yr0GBVX9boD-PRkJSAGpwVTAUzIB4oIjehBirxuj1emWM-1iiXSuUKiBacOR-7QWPx65JlNpjPILNgHN0fOezDesAAZhLgfLIcr1YFb384igZOAzAcFAA8tHunHKQBJEDyZOp8gzucL5er5DACwgZh9kDIftjyAsPnh5AAWmQAHFmMxTBtoWfTxYjEkBBIFMHAgA)

**RECURSION**

```js
type RemoveDollar<
  T extends string,
  Result extends string = ''
  > =
  (T extends `${infer Head}${infer Rest}`
    ? (Rest extends ''
      ? (Head extends '$' ? Result : `${Result}${Head}`) : RemoveDollar<Rest, `${Result}${Head}`>) : never
  )

/**
 * First cycle
 */

type Call = RemoveDollar<'foo$'>

type First<
  T extends string,
  Result extends string = ''
  > =
  // T extends        `{f}         {oo$}
  (T extends `${infer Head}${infer Rest}`
    ? (Rest extends '' // Rest is not empty
      // This branch is skipped on first iteration         
      ? (Head extends '$' ? Result : `${Result}${Head}`)
      // RemoveDollar<'oo$', ${''}${f}>
      : RemoveDollar<Rest, `${Result}${Head}`>
    ) : never
  )

/**
 * Second cycle
 */
type Second<
  T extends string,
  // Result is f
  Result extends string = ''
  > =
  // T extends       `{o}$         {o$}
  (T extends `${infer Head}${infer Rest}`
    ? (Rest extends '' // Rest is not empty
      // This branch is skipped on second iteration         
      ? (Head extends '$' ? Result : `${Result}${Head}`)
      // RemoveDollar<'o$', ${'f'}${o}>
      : RemoveDollar<Rest, `${Result}${Head}`>
    ) : never
  )

/**
* Third cycle
*/
type Third<
  T extends string,
  // Result is fo
  Result extends string = ''
  > =
  // T extends       `{o}          {$}
  (T extends `${infer Head}${infer Rest}`
    ? (Rest extends '' // Rest is not empty, it is $
      // This branch is skipped on third iteration         
      ? (Head extends '$' ? Result : `${Result}${Head}`)
      // RemoveDollar<'$', ${'fo'}${o}>
      : RemoveDollar<Rest, `${Result}${Head}`>
    ) : never
  )

/**
* Fourth cycle, the last one
*/
type Fourth<
  T extends string,
  // Result is foo
  Result extends string = ''
  > =
  // T extends       `${$}        {''}
  (T extends `${infer Head}${infer Rest}`
    ? (Rest extends '' // Rest is  empty
      // Head is $           foo   
      ? (Head extends '$' ? Result : `${Result}${Head}`)
      // This branch is skipped on last iteration
      : RemoveDollar<Rest, `${Result}${Head}`>
    ) : never
  )
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAICVoFsD2A3aARFAbHBDAJwB5hZYAVWaAD1GgDsATAZ1hdEIEsGBzAGjIJoLAK45Q1Oo1btOPXrAC8sAOSqhAPmVCAFFVr1mbAAYASAN48AZtEKwAEtHxMAvpZt3hHVyaHkAflhdRA4pI1l1f3JYIN0nF3CZNlUzVVjvcUkALlhzC1Cs9wsEtxMASlhcxFQMbDwiYlDQfjzLQoli0t9NStyGaAxCIXKQAHoAKgmyCdgAMS5CMIBjcGWcaBmxkAgYWABhfDxlYVqsXAISVWsUFDTNHag4BaXQUnIDaWM5bj5Bcg6kkMyR%20ChOUXI2iUQjGY0oSW%20MSRJgs1lcSIxFluZlcek%20EVMHgYtns3SJJO8oF80TizQRkXSsMpsC4bAYKCBSEgEGi5CZFAAFqzYAAjQj4BjLAUstgsADWXEgMCYsBQDFg1kWYS49HFoC4aoxSN5GXizhVwO%20qXSQUBVTaBRERUs3QqJqZNXQ5waV2xqlalnUxTRDyN1WQXvqlyaIhaDsBXXNPWifVgAyGI3GUxmsAAytBlmqVat1ptYBNtrs4PnC8x3vDLbIOL8BDC4XbhdYhHbG7L5HxwRpITo%20XD8SCjSiUO4jTEsTi8fTCVZiV4ySuKc1qUjabGl2pGe298L2ZzueB3WOhWwxRKpTL2AqldAVYaWAWiyzdfh9YbZ7ATTiUp92tDI7VyfIExdJM3SND0IzqC5GlUO5-VgQNrFUYpp1DDFwzOKNGmaVpIKdTpoJcZMkVTdM7EzYBJmmWZBUWYs1g2YAKzAJ5KCFQgmHrcdvmbBR-lgeCxAkB8bm7MigS%20Jt%200UFQIVgKE2wbBS2EnLF0X-WALAXch9H3fJPFJJNyS8Lc-B3YI6V7A9xKPbU2Q5aguQgVodQfMxL144Vb0laVhXlRVlVVdVQD4lUdTsH8DXVf9AOCYDHNA205PtUjJKpCiylGOCjwIpCrjSAMLGuFAsMsHCTXwyNSpjDgSPaOTE0okxcPIGjBjonqsyY%20YUFEQhotgEsNlaaK4AIMI1U2Liq2G0bosE-cRL%20DSOzYG4UFk3KNqUwctBHZzNIJWd8hxf9KqwxdHLM1cLMoqz7Bsml7L3dLD2ZYUPPPfzgOFMx9PIPaYhSs1EnStIwKyiC2tyjqCv8lib3FYKHzC59X3VObJDivVEvq05Gp9Zq4xy50Shg7rYF6jMeqAA)

Comment: Recursive types, waoh! But how does the inference work in ```T extends `${infer Head}${infer Rest}` ```?
What will be Head and Rest on the first cycle for, say, 'owner$'?
(also, thanks for a quick answer! I'll accept @Jean-Alphonse answer for conciseness but will definitely note yours)

Comment: @Bob made an update. Sure, no problem. Mine seems to be an overengineered

Comment: Ok, by default, the 1st inference takes the 1st character. Thanks for taking the time to explain!